# SqlAlchemy - Nested relationship loading behaviour

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I use SqlAlchemy to manage queries with my database, but i have a problem.
I have 3 Tables defined here:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orders = relationship("Order", backref=backref("payer", uselist=True, lazy='dynamic'), foreign_keys="Order.user_id", order_by="desc(Order.date)")
    gifts = relationship("Order", backref=backref("receiver", uselist=False), foreign_keys="Order.user_target_id", order_by="desc(Order.date)")

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user_target_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    partner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('partner.id'))

class Partner(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orders = relationship("Order", backref=backref("partner", uselist=False))
```

I would like to get all the "gifts" for a user, and for each gift (an Order object) i expect to get the 'payer', 'receiver' and 'partner' relations filled.

I am really new with SqlAlchemy so maybe that i have badly configured my relationships.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: What are you asking? Does the code not work? Barring the incorrect `uselist=True` I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinaisons, mixing useliste=true/false, and change the lazylaoder strategy, and finally it works(see my reply).
My last question is: why does it works with default lazyloader configuration and not with lazy='dynamic" ?

Comment: Because dynamic doesn't support the "one" side of a relationship. dynamic gives you a query to work with, and it's the decision of the author to not support the case where the query would just give you one row.